# Matrix $BA\neq$$I_{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $\text{A}$ is a $2\times3$ matrix and $\text{B}$ is a $3\times2$ matrix, prove that $\text{BA}=I_{3}$ is impossible.

So I've been thinking about this, and so far I'm thinking that a homogenous system is going to be involved in this proof. Maybe something about one of the later steps being that the last row of the matrix would be $0\neq \text{a}$, where a is any real number. I've also been thinking that for a $2\times3$ matrix, there is a (non-zero) vector $[x,y,z]$ such that $\text{A}[x,y,z]=[0,0]$ because the dot product could possibly yield $0$. I'm not sure if that's helpful at all though.

Trouble is I'm not really too sure how to continue, or even begin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would go with your latter thoughts: suppose you have a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Av=0$.  Then compute $BAv$ as $B(Av)$ and $(BA)v$...

Comment: This title is a little messy, because $I_3$ exists!

Comment: Haha, right you are. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the possible dimension of the columnspace of the matrix $BA$. In particular, since $A$ has at most a two-dimensional columnspace, $BA$ has at most a two-dimensional columnspace. Stated more formally, if $A$ has rank $r_a$ and $B$ has rank $r_b$, then $BA$ has rank at most $\min\{ r_a, r_b \}$.